# SQL Statement in JQGRID is returning a null when it returns a value in SQL

Tags: jquery, sql, jqgrid, ibm-midrange

The following code returns a null in the second column (STSEL).  When I run the SQL statement independently it returns a 'Y' or an 'N' as expected.

I cannot see why it is doing this. Any help is much appreciated.

Note: I echoed the results of $response directly and it show null so it is not the grid configuration causing this.

```
$where = "a.VER = (SELECT max(e.CVER) FROM prodlib.vercntl e WHERE e.VERDTE <= 20151031) 
      AND a.LVL2 like 'RRG%' AND substr(a.LVL4,1,2) = '00' AND b.TYPE = 'SCT'  
      AND d.ST = '$state' AND d.LSEQ = $seq";

$sql = "SELECT LROWID, STSEL, ST, STORE, STNAME, CLSEQ, LVL4
      FROM 
      ( SELECT row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY 1 asc ) AS rid, d.LROWID, (CASE WHEN (d.ST is not null) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) as STSEL, c.ST, a.STOR, a.NAME, c.CLSEQ, a.LVL4
          FROM prodlib.smpmt a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN prodlib.dmpcv b ON a.ST = substr(b.FD1,1,2)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN devlib.pyp280c@ c ON a.st = c.ST
            LEFT OUTER JOIN devlib.pyp280l@ d ON c.ST=d.ST AND c.CLSEQ=d.LSEQ AND a.STOR = d.STOR
          WHERE $where
      ) AS t
      WHERE (t.rid BETWEEN 1 AND 20) ORDER BY STSEL desc, STORE";

if ($conn) {

$stmt = db2_exec($conn, $sql);

$response = (object) array('page' => $page, 'total' => $total_pages, 'records' =>$rowcount, 'rows' => "");

$response->page = $page;
$response->total = $total_pages;
$response->records = $rowcount;
$i=0;
while ($row = db2_fetch_object($stmt)) {
$response->rows[$i]['id']=trim($row->LROWID);
$response->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row->LROWID, $row->STSEL, $row->ST, $row->STORE, $row->STNAME, $row->CLSEQ, $row->LVL4);
$i++;
} 

echo json_encode($response);
```

Thank you much and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try using coalesce instead?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

coalesce(d.ST,'N') replaces all null values with N

Comment: Thank you, that cleans up the code a bit but $response still has nulls for all rows, regardless of the SQL results.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works.  I'm not sure exactly why it does not work the first way.

```
if (is_null($row->ROWID)) {
    $STSEL = 'N';
}  else  {
    $STSEL = 'Y';
}
$response->rows[$i]['id'] = trim($row->LROWID);
$response->rows[$i]['cell'] = array($row->LROWID, $STSEL, $row->ST, $row->STORE, $row->STNAME, $row->CLSEQ, $row->LVL4);
$i++;
```